# Explain how a golf ball and a football can have the same kinetic energy even if their masses are different

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy

I know that this is possible, but I just don't know how to explain for a question on my assignment

the formula for kinetic energy is $E_{k}=\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of energy (Kinetic (+ rotational), potential etc.)
Let's just talk about kinetic energy. This is determined by how fast something moves and how heavy it is.

The formula is:

$$E_{kin} = \dfrac{m\cdot v^2}{2}$$

So if you either increase the velocity OR the mass, the kinetic energy will increase aswell.
This means that a ball with lower mass would need to be faster to have the same kinetic energy:

We want both energies to be equal:

$$E_{kin,1} = E_{kin,2}$$
$$\rightarrow\dfrac{m_1\cdot v_1^2}{2}=\dfrac{m_2\cdot v_2^2}{2}$$

This can be solved for the speed/mass.